# how do I execute a variable, in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh

I have a very basic function.

```
t() {
[[ -f ./terragrunt.hcl ]] && local exe=terragrunt
[[ ! -f ./terragrunt.hcl ]] && local exe=terraform

[[ ! $exe ]] && echo -e "\033[31;1m[ERROR]\033[0m Can't figure out what to run. Please run manually"
local cmd="$exe $@"
[[ $DEBUG ]] && echo -e "\033[34;1m[DEBUG]\033[0m executable is $exe.
Args are $@
Command to be run: $cmd"
$cmd
}
```

However, when I run it like `t outputs`
It returns `t:9: command not found: terraform output`

I can run `terraform output` and get the proper output.

I have tried `eval` and `return` as well, neither work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cmd` at all; there's no good way to *correctly* encode a valid command line in a single string.

```
t() {
    [[ -f ./terragrunt.hcl ]] && local exe=terragrunt
    [[ ! -f ./terragrunt.hcl ]] && local exe=terraform
    
    [[ ! $exe ]] && echo -e "\033[31;1m[ERROR]\033[0m Can't figure out what to run. Please run manually"
    [[ $DEBUG ]] && echo -e "\033[34;1m[DEBUG]\033[0m executable is $exe.
    Args are $@
    Command to be run: $exe $@"

    "$exe" "$@"
}
```

Constructing an accurate string representation of the command resulting from an arbitrary value of `$@` is non-trivial and barely worth doing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing:

```
local cmd="$exe $@"
```

This constucts a single string out of `$exe` and `$@`, and when you use `$cmd` it will try to run that string as a command, including spaces, as if you had typed `"terraform output"` (which will try to look up `/bin/terraform output`) rather than `terraform output`. Hence your error:

```
t:9: command not found: terraform output
```

The easiest way to deal with this in zsh is to use arrays:

```
local cmd=($exe $@)
$cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Word splitting occurs before parameter expansion in zsh. In your case, you would have to use

```
${(z)cmd}
```

to tell zsh that you want to have an extra round of word splitting after the expansion. However, this will word-split **everything** inside `cmd`. I you want to avoid this, make `cmd` an array , where the command itself is the first element and each subsequent element is a an argument, and invoke it as

```
$cmd[@]
```